# How can I change shadow color of active top Tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-tabs

I want to change the shadow color of the active top tab. How can I do that?
Like the following picture, I want to change the blue color to red color.

[image]

**My Code**

```
import {Image, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import StudyingScreen from './StudyingScreen';
import CollectionScreen from './CollectionScreen';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const MyCourses = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 15, marginBottom: 15}}>
        My Courses
      </Text>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarIndicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: 'red'},
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="STUDYING" component={StudyingScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="COLLECTION" component={CollectionScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyCourses;
```

Answer (score 2):

A super simple prop is [there](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#tabbarindicatorstyle), just read the doc carefully.

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarIndicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: 'red'}
  }}
>
  {/* ... */}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Example: https://snack.expo.dev/SiW0Hun-I

Notice: your code seems right, check your `react-navigation` version.